# pivot/transpose without aggregation MS SQL 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

(MS SQL 2014)(SQL beginner)
I have two columns of data with repeated values:

```
CLAIMID adacode
10009   D1110
10009   D1330
10009   D1206
10010   D0120
10010   D0274
10010   D1110
10010   D1330
10011   D4341
10011   D4341
ETC. (CURRENTLY 4000+ ROWS)
```

Each CLAIMID can have up to 4 adacodes.  I want to convert the listing to this (I need the adacode, not a count of how many):

```
CLAIMID ada1    ada2    ada3    ada4
10009   d1110   d1330   d1206
10010   d0120   d0274   d1110   d1330
10011   d4341   d4341
etc.
```

I've tried pivot without aggregation, grouping without success.  I've also researched other similar code snippets, without success.  I don't think this is too complex, but as someone who has a whole 2 weeks of SQL programming experience, what am I missing?  The following code (without pivot or group) gives me the data I need to transpose:

```
SELECT  dbo.claim_base.CLAIMID, dbo.PROC_CODE_BASE.adacode

FROM    dbo.claim_base, dbo.proc_log_base, dbo.PROC_CODE_BASE

WHERE   dbo.claim_base.CLAIMID = dbo.proc_log_base.claimID
AND dbo.proc_log_base.PROC_CODEID = dbo.PROC_CODE_BASE.PROC_CODEID
AND dbo.PROC_CODE_BASE.adacode <> 'payment'
;
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you are learning to use SQL learn to NEVER use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, standard `JOIN` syntax.

Second, table aliases make queries easier to write and to read.

You can do what you want using conditional aggregation and `row_number()`:

```
SELECT CLAIMID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN adacode END) as adacode_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 2 THEN adacode END) as adacode_2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 3 THEN adacode END) as adacode_3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 4 THEN adacode END) as adacode_4
FROM (SELECT cb.CLAIMID, pcb.adacode,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cb.CLAIMID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) as seqnum
      FROM dbo.claim_base cb JOIN
           dbo.proc_log_base plb
           ON cb.CLAIMID = plb.claimID JOIN
           dbo.PROC_CODE_BASE pcb
           ON plb.PROC_CODEID = pcb.PROC_CODEID
      WHERE pcb.adacode <> 'payment'
     ) ca
GROUP BY CLAIMID
```

Comment: Gordon, Thank you for this.  It gave the results I need and answered my question completely.  Now I can take some downtime and review your code, to fully understand how/why it works.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use pivot, you can make use of row number, so that aggregation function does not miss any row. As a given claim can have more than 1 code, use of row number will be helpful.

```
select '10009' as ClaimID, 'D1110' as AdaCode into #tmp union all 
select '10009' as ClaimID, 'D1330' as AdaCode  union all 
select '10009' as ClaimID, 'D1206' as AdaCode  union all 
select '10010' as ClaimID, 'D0120' as AdaCode  union all 
select '10010' as ClaimID, 'D0274' as AdaCode  union all 
select '10010' as ClaimID, 'D1110' as AdaCode  union all 
select '10010' as ClaimID, 'D1330' as AdaCode  union all 
select '10011' as ClaimID, 'D4341' as AdaCode  union all 
select '10011' as ClaimID, 'D4341' as AdaCode   


SELECT * FROM   
(
    SELECT 
        t.claimid, t.AdaCode, concat('ada', ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by claimid  order by adacode)) rownum 
    FROM 
        #tmp t
) t 
PIVOT(
    max(AdaCode ) 
    FOR rownum IN (
        [ada1] , 
        [ada2] ,
        [ada3] ,
       [ada4])
) AS pivot_table
```

Output:

[image]